# AWS IAM policy permissions clash issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ami

I have tried to create a policy that will prevent the deregistration of AMIs, *unless* the AMIs have the appropriate "delete this" tag. When I run the IAM policy simulator, the policy doesn't seem to work and the AMIs are allowed to be deregistered, because users already are associated with policies that are more permissive than my new policy.

Is it possible to make my custom policy take priority over other policies? Or do I have to create new policies that explicitly do *not* have the Deregister AMI permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following IAM policy will deny deregistration of an AMI (just replace with your concrete resource ARN) when said AMI *does not* have the "delete" tag or that tag's value is *not* "yes". This works regardless of any possible *Allow* permissions that the calling identity might have.

This is because permission statements with "Deny" action always take precedence over any Allow permissions.

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "ec2:DeregisterImage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:ResourceTag/delete": "yes"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Read this page for the detailed algorithm IAM uses to evaluate permissions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect, at least not when I test with the Policy Simulator. However, it does seem to work the way I expected with _real_ AMIs. Also, this won't have an impact on auto-expiring AMIs created by AWS Backup, will it?

Comment: I wanted it to be easy to delete AMIs _unless_ they are tagged them so I switched the condition to "StringEquals" and the Tag is named "Preserve", so: Deny deregistration if AMI is tagged with "Preserve=yes".

Comment: Unfortunately the Policy Simulator does not match the real world, especially when using conditions e.g. "If you leave the value for a condition key empty, then that key is ignored during the simulation" from a Warning call-out in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html)